# CoreML Compile Error after changing multiArray type

Tags: xcode, coreml, coremltools, tflite, mlmodel

I am trying to use a converted '.mlmodel' from Google MediaPipe '.tflite'.

However, after changing the type of the multiArray, a CoreML compile error occurs and cannot be resolved.

The input type of mlmodel could be changed as follows.

```
# convert_inputType.py :convert multiArray to image type
import coremltools as ct
from coremltools.proto import FeatureTypes_pb2 as ft

spec = ct.utils.load_spec('model_coreml_float32.mlmodel') # miltiArray type
builder = ct.models.neural_network.NeuralNetworkBuilder(spec=spec)

# check input/output features
print('--- Before change:')
builder.inspect_input_features()
builder.inspect_output_features()

# change the input so the model can accept 256x256 RGB images
input = spec.description.input[0]
# del input.type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
input.type.imageType.colorSpace = ft.ImageFeatureType.RGB
input.type.imageType.width = 256
input.type.imageType.height = 256

# converted input/output features
print('--- After change:')
builder.inspect_input_features()
builder.inspect_output_features()

# save inputType-converted model
ct.utils.save_spec(spec, 'selfie_segmentation.mlmodel') # changed type
```

```
--- Before change:

[Id: 0] Name: input_1
          Type: multiArrayType {
  shape: 1
  shape: 256
  shape: 256
  shape: 3
  dataType: FLOAT32
}

[Id: 0] Name: activation_10
          Type: multiArrayType {
  dataType: FLOAT32
}

--- After change:

[Id: 0] Name: input_1
          Type: imageType {
  width: 256
  height: 256
  colorSpace: RGB
}

[Id: 0] Name: activation_10
          Type: multiArrayType {
  dataType: FLOAT32
}
```

- 'model_coreml_float32.mlmodel' :converted from MediaPipe TFlite at  [PINTO_model_zoo](https://github.com/PINTO0309/PINTO_model_zoo/tree/main/109_Selfie_Segmentation)
- 'selfie_segmentation.mlmodel' :changed-type mlmode, saved

The following error occurs when loading the changed-type mlmodel into Xcode Peoject.

```
Espresso exception: "Invalid blob shape": generic_elementwise_kernel: cannot broadcast:
----------------------------------------
SchemeBuildError: Failed to build the scheme "testSelfieSegmentation"

compiler error:  Espresso exception: "Invalid blob shape": generic_elementwise_kernel: cannot broadcast:

Compile CoreML model selfie_segmentation.mlmodel:
coremlc: error: compiler error:  Espresso exception: "Invalid blob shape": generic_elementwise_kernel: cannot broadcast:
 (1, 16, 8, 128)
 (1, 16, 2, 128)
```

I have checked the model configuration with [Newtron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron), and cannot find any layer like (1,16,8,128) or (1,16,2,128) which in the error message.

Is there something wrong with the change code? or does it have something to do with converted multiArray-type shape mlmodel?, Perhaps, I guess that the shape of (1,256,256,3) should be (3,256,256), but I don't know how to change it.

Any tips would be appreciated.